# Чтение html-файла в Python by PyCharm. Не могу получить данные по классу

Tags: python, html, файлы, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import random
from selenium import webdriver
import time


def get_source(url):
    s = Service(r"C:\Users\rakal\PycharmProjects\skraping_bot_for_momy\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

    driver.maximize_window()
    try:
        driver.get(url=url)
        time.sleep(3)

        with open("source_page.html", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(driver.page_source)
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(_ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


def get_items_urls(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        src = file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml", encoding="utf-8")
    items_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="aga2")
    urls = []
    for item in items_divs:
        item_url = item.find("a").get("href")
        urls.append(item_url)
    with open("items_urls.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for url in urls:
            file.write(f"{url}\n")
    return '[INFO] Urls collected!'


def main():
    #get_source(url="https://www.ozon.ru/category/podguzniki-i-trusiki-30749/?deny_category_prediction=true&from_global=true&isdiscount=t&text=подгузники")
    get_items_urls(file_path=r"C:\Users\rakal\PycharmProjects\skraping_bot_for_momy\source_page.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rakal\PycharmProjects\skraping_bot_for_momy\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\rakal\PycharmProjects\skraping_bot_for_momy\main.py", line 45, in main
    get_items_urls(file_path=r"C:\Users\rakal\PycharmProjects\skraping_bot_for_momy\source_page.html")
  File "C:\Users\rakal\PycharmProjects\skraping_bot_for_momy\main.py", line 29, in get_items_urls
    src = file.read()
  File "C:\Users\rakal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 276732: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: попробуйте к  with open("items_urls.txt", 'w') добавить encoding="utf8". если не поможет, дайте весь код.

Comment: Приложил полный код!